# How do I check whether a mobile device has already been registered

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm using the Amazon AWS Ruby SDK for Amazon SNS but I'm having some trouble with devices already being registered. Sometimes when a device gets registered again I get an error like `AWS::SNS::Errors::InvalidParameter Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Endpoint arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:**** already exists with the same Token, but different attributes.`. How do I check whether an endpoint already exists and more importantly, how do I get the endpoint for a given token?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with SNS for node.js. Have you found some solutions to this?

Comment: I am using the .net lib and I don't get an error when I try to register it again

Comment: You only get the error when you want to store additional attributes associated with the registration and then later on you call register with different set of attributes.

Comment: I'm afraid my solution is to use a Regex to extract it from the error message... There seems to be no way to check whether the device already exists

Answer (score 13):

Credit to BvdBijl's idea, I made an extension method to delete the existing one if found and then add it.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model;

namespace Amazon.SimpleNotificationService
{
    public static class AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClientExtensions
    {
        private const string existingEndpointRegexString = "Reason: Endpoint (.+) already exists with the same Token";
        private static Regex existingEndpointRegex = new Regex(existingEndpointRegexString);
        public static CreatePlatformEndpointResponse CreatePlatformEndpointIdempotent(
            this AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient client,
            CreatePlatformEndpointRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = client.CreatePlatformEndpoint(request);
                return result;
            }
            catch (AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceException e)
            {
                if (e.ErrorCode == "InvalidParameter")
                {
                    var match = existingEndpointRegex.Match(e.Message);
                    if (match.Success) {
                        string arn = match.Groups[1].Value;
                        client.DeleteEndpoint(new DeleteEndpointRequest
                        {
                             EndpointArn = arn,
                        });
                        return client.CreatePlatformEndpoint(request);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So crazy that this is literally the only way I can see to do it as well.

Comment: Instead of deleting and creating platform endpoint you could just call: 

    SetEndpointAttributes

with attribute 

`Enabled = true`

Comment: Feels strange having to parse this out of an error message that could change in the future. Kind of ridiculous that they don't just return the duplicate endpoint arn to us.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like amazone resolved this issue.
I'm using RoR and used to have same problem when trying to register and existing GCM code I got an error message saying

```
"AWS::SNS::Errors::InvalidParameter Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Endpoint arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:**** already exists with the same Token, but different attributes."
```

although I used same (empty) attributes.  Now when I send an existing GCM code (with same attributes as the original one) I get the endpoint arn and not the error message.

Answer (score 0):

ListEndpointsByPlatformApplication only return 100 endpoints, you have to use nextToken to get more. Here is my implementation.

```
    public void deleteEndpoint(string token, string PlatformApplicationArn)
    {
        ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest listRequest = new ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest();
        listRequest.PlatformApplicationArn = PlatformApplicationArn;
        Logger.Info("Deleting endpoint with token -> " + token);
        var list = snsClient.ListEndpointsByPlatformApplication(listRequest);
        do
        {
            foreach (var x in list.Endpoints.Where(x => x.Attributes["Token"] == token))
            {
                snsClient.DeleteEndpoint(new DeleteEndpointRequest() { EndpointArn = x.EndpointArn });
                Logger.Info("Endpoint removed-> " + x.EndpointArn);
                return;
            }

            listRequest.NextToken = list.NextToken;
            list = snsClient.ListEndpointsByPlatformApplication(listRequest);
        }
        while (list.NextToken != null);

    }
```

Comment: Consider if i have plenty of end points means 1 lakh, then this process will take some what delay right for checking the token in total end points. Is there any way to delete endpoint directly without processing?