# AWS SNS Error Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Endpoint xxx already exists with the same Token, but different attributes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, amazon-web-services

Using AWS SDK for iOS v2.0.8

Quick question:

How do I `[snsClient deleteEndpoint:request]`, when I do not know this endpoint's arn? I do have the deviceToken.

Detail:

I am receiving the error `Token Reason: Endpoint arn:aws:sns:...c6 already exists with the same Token, but different attributes` when I attempt to create an endpoint for my iPhone:

```
// Async call to create the platform endpoint
[[[_awsSnsClient createPlatformEndpoint:request] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    // success
    _awsPlatformEndpoint = task.result; // Save off the endpoint data
    [self awsUsubscribeAllSubscriptions];
    return nil;
}] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        // failed with error
        ALog(@"Error: Code:%li localizedDesc:%@ Exception:%@", (long)task.error.code, task.error.localizedDescription, task.exception);
        if(task.error.code == 7) {
            // delete offending endpoint and create it again?
        }
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

When I create the endpoint I do not set the `attributes`, I do set `customUserData` based on client data which can change. In the [SDK docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput.html) for `customUserData` it says: *Arbitrary user data to associate with the endpoint. Amazon SNS does not use this data. The data must be in UTF-8 format and less than 2KB.*

When I delete the endpoint from the SNS console, I can get a new endpoint. So how do I deleteEndpoint, when I do not know this endpoint's arn? I can see the arn in the AWS logging, but not in the BFTask* error object.

I've seen the ruby solution at [19551067](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551067/how-do-i-check-whether-a-mobile-device-has-already-been-registered), but I do not see a way the read the message, the ruby example reads the message from the exception, task.exception == nil in my case. I received from AWS verbose logging:

Using AWS logging:

```
2014-10-01 06:48:54.489 myApp[1665:1345740] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:244 | -[AWSXMLResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body: [<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameter</Code>
    <Message>Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Endpoint arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:245211809793:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/myApp-Dev/7bxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxc6 already exists with the same Token, but different attributes.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>d874ac10-e6de-5a4d-805e-e0b6ee58e5b7</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
]
```

What I can get from (BFTask* task).error:

```
2014-10-01 06:48:54.494 myApp[1665:1345740] __46-[AppDelegate_Shared awsStartWithDeviceToken:]_block_invoke1279 [Line 3558] Error: 
  Code:7 
  localizedDesc:The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain error 7.)
  Exception:(null)
```

** Update 2014-10-01 **

My development iPad started doing this just after updating to iOS 8.0.2. I *do* add the version number into the `customUserData` - but Amazon SNS does not use this field... right?

** Update 2014-01-01 19:06 GMT-07:00 **

Added `task.error.userInfo` to the error block. I'll parse the message and delete the endpoint when this comes up. An option in `AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput` to override this error, update the endpoint and return the endpoint would be nice ;)

thank you!

Console now has:

```
2014-10-01 18:58:50.836 iFlightBag[1862:1493821] __46-[AppDelegate_Shared     awsStartWithDeviceToken:]_block_invoke1281 [Line 3559] Error: 
Code:7 
localDesc:The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain error 7.) 
Exception:(null) 
userInfo:{
    Code = InvalidParameter;
    Message = "Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Endpoint arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:245211809793:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/LevelFlightMobile-Dev/7b70d2c4-846e-3afd-a1ba-eedaa00f7ac6 already exists with the same Token, but different attributes.";
    Type = Sender;
    "__text" =     (
        "\n    ",
        "\n    ",
        "\n    ",
        "\n  "
    );
}
```

Comment: Is there any update on this? Parsing the error seems liek an unstable solution since Amazon could change the error message at will.

Comment: @Zigglzworth No, I am currently parsing the endpoint from the message. So far, it's survived 3 API updates ;) I've sent in a request to add a "delete endpoint if exists" flag in the request object.

Comment: Ok. I have done the same (parsed the error message). I'll follow your lead and send in a request regarding this as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userInfo` property of `task.error` should contains a dictionary representation of the error XML.